# Access 2003 - Capitalize first letter using queries

Tags: ms-access

Hi

How I can capitalize the first letter and all other letters in lower case? I need to do this **using queries from own Access**.

Example, if I have stored countries: SPAIN, FRANCE, ITALY, ....I want to change them to: Spain, Italy, France,....

Thanks in advance

---

**Solution**

```
update COUNTRY set CO= StrConv ([CO], 3)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at [MS Access: StrConv Function](http://www.techonthenet.com/access/functions/string/strconv.php)